# Receive an empty log file from FTP client while connecting to Azure - because log is "in use"

Tags: java, azure, logging, ftp-client, is-empty

**Problem is :**

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
```

ofcourse i have all the connection details here and than :

```
InputStream inputStream = client.retrieveFileStream( file.getName());
System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
```

**The output:**

```
550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by 
another process.
```

How can I take this log-file anyway?

**Here is the full code :**

```
public static void retrieveLogFilesFTP() {
        try {

            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

        for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {

            client.connect(ENV_PROD);
            client.login([loginUserName], [loginPassword]);
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            client.changeWorkingDirectory("/site/wwwroot");


                FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();

                if (ftpFiles != null && ftpFiles.length > 0) {


                    for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {
                        if (file.getName().startsWith("httpplatform")) {


                            File currentDirectory = new File(PATH + components[i]);
                            if (!currentDirectory.exists()) {
                                currentDirectory.mkdir();
                            }

                            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(currentDirectory + "/" + file.getName(), false);
                            client.retrieveFile(file.getName(), output);


                            System.out.println(client.getReplyString());

                            output.close()


                        }

                    }

                }


            client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
            changeLogFilesNames(new File(PATH + "/" + components[i] + "/"), components[i]);


        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to download the file from Azure using `retrieveFileStream()`. You may have a try.

```
...
InputStream inputStream = client.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(currentDirectory + "/" + file.getName(), false);

//Using org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, output);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);

System.out.println(client.getReplyString())
...
```